# Bootstrap tooltip disable button Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to add tooltip on disabled button

Sometime it's work with Firefox, sometime with Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/danq3r8n/11/

```
<!-- Work only with Chrome !-->
<button disabled>
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="test">
        Disable
    </div>
</button>

<!-- Work only with Firefox !-->
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="test" disabled>
    Disable
</button>
```

But I didn't success to make a disabled button with tooltip with can work on Firefox AND Chrome.

What's the problem with bootstrap tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a [know issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9294) with how the browsers work, and in the documentation for v4 they are saying you should wrap the button, quote from site:

> Tooltips for `.disabled` or `disabled` elements must be triggered on a wrapper element.

[v4 source](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/)

Upon further digging, it is also stated in the v3 documentation as such

> ## Tooltips on disabled elements require wrapper elements
>
> To add a tooltip to a disabled or .disabled element, put the element inside of a  and apply the tooltip to that  instead.

[v3 source](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: Thanks, saved me from scouring the V4 documentation.